# Bootstrap 4.1 fixed div with overflow-y and full width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I try to make two cols with two tables. Right table must be fixed and auto  overflow. But if I do that, table will be not width 100% of col (full width of col). I'm using bootstrap 4.1. Maybe there are any bootstrap solutions to do that? Or something else?

How it will by works: when user select in left table some row, all additional data will be loaded and disblayed on right table.

```css
#table_div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-6">
      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">r1</th>
            <th scope="col">r2</th>
            <th scope="col">r3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <div id="table_div">
          <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="my_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">r1</th>
                <th scope="col">r2</th>
                <th scope="col">r3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**REAL DATA** - https://jsfiddle.net/hdb1783y/4/

Comment: you want the tow tabels be 100%

Comment: @לבנימלכה add fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hdb1783y/4/ . I wnant like there, but with fixed and auto overflow-y right table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `abc` class on the required div and this style

```
.abc {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%!important;
}
```

```css
.abc {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-6">
      <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">r1</th>
            <th scope="col">r2</th>
            <th scope="col">r3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div>
        <div id="table_div" class="abc">
          <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="my_table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">r1</th>
                <th scope="col">r2</th>
                <th scope="col">r3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add fiddle with real data - https://jsfiddle.net/hdb1783y/4/. If run your example (click "run code snoppet") right table is not fixed

Comment: no. I whant fixed right table. When I scroll down the page I want right table will by always on my eyes. See my example in question - run it. If scroll down page right table always on one place. I must see it all time I scrolling the page. Bit in my solution (see question on top) table compressed. So i need fixed right table (table must follow my when scrolling the page) and this table must be 100% width ot coll width)

Comment: Yes! But `width:49%` - it is not very good. this is not elastic

Comment: Yeah but you have to add width to fixed elemenets otherwise they take up width according to the content

Comment: .abc {max-height: 100vh; overflow: auto; position: sticky;top: 0;} - this is works in real data - https://jsfiddle.net/hdb1783y/23/

Comment: position: sticky; is not yet supported by all browsers.. but you can use it if thats not a concern

Answer (score 0):

Here, You will not need to write custom css. have already predefined bootstrap class available for that. You can use `pre-scrollable` and `position-fixed` bootstrap class for add vertical scrollbar and fixed position of element.

Update Jsfiddle demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdb1783y/27/)

Comment: but what about width? width now not 100% of col. Now table take up width according to the content